# React Native iOS Debugging Physical Device WebSocket Connection Failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, react-native

WebSocket connection failed with error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 thrown when trying to run react-native on physical iOS device. It does on run simulator.

This is not a duplicate post. I have read all other stack overflow posts with similar issues and tried their suggestions, none of them resolve this issue (some are out of date and actually cause additional issues).

1. React packager is running on `port 8081`

[image]

2. I am on the same wifi network and without any firewall issues preventing communicating with the development server. I can open safari on the device and load the development server by IP host machine IP address.

[image]

3. I have cleared watchman, using `watchman watch-del-all`
4. Trying to change `RCTWebSocketExecutor.m` to use my host machine's ip address instead of localhost does not work and prevents the pre-bundle file from loading. DON'T DO THIS. It is an out of date recommendation from old documentation on the react-native site.
5. Tried running clean & build again in XCode, restarting XCode, restarting machine, deleting the app from device and reinstalling.
6. Updating `jsCodelocation` to the following does not work either.

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xx.xx.110.78:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

I am out of ideas for getting debugging to work again... I may have to open an issue on github with the react-native team but there could be something I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to react-native 0.33 (from 0.31) fixed this issue magically.

Answer (score 0):

Does the packager also stop after `<END> Building Dependency Graph`? I have this issue when my Mac and my iPhone are connected through my home wifi network. Setting up a direct wifi connection between Mac and iPhone works, but that's not really a good workaround

Comment: No it does not stop at `<END> Building Dependency Graph`. In fact, if I refresh the app, I can see `<START> request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false` so the app is able to communicate with the server on some level.

Answer (score -1):

Init a brand new Project with RN 0.33, then run it on a emulator, see if you can open the dev tool on Chrome.

If you can open the dev tool, then there is nothing need to be edit. Just close the Chrome and start the app on your device, ...

Comment: Destroying my entire project and starting from scratch is not an option, nor a solution to the issue. I have restarted chrome, the device and cleaned the build folder several times without any luck.

Comment: I mean you can start a new project to see if your dev tool works with the new project. So maybe you can be one step closer to your solution. You can do it without editing any thing of you old project.